plugin 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2' doesnt add and firebase authentication sdk doesnt connect
I'm currently working on login/register activity in Android Studio (Koala Feature Drop 2024.1.2 Patch 1) with the use of Firebase. I connected my app to Firebase, but when it came to "add the firebase authentication SDK to your app" Android Studio gave me this:
build.gradle (project-level)

    Add rules to include the Google Services Gradle plugin:
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2' 


this is my build.gradle file (project level)
(i thought id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false is the thing i need to add, i added it but nothing is working....)
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.google.services)
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false

}

and this is build.gradle file (app level)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.projectb"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.projectb"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.3.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0")
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.firebase.auth)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)

}


i read here someone got the problem solved by simply creating new project and doing everything again with firebase, i tried it too, but doesnt work for me unfortunately... and i followed firebase instructions about json file, it is in app folder:(((((
sorry im really new to android app coding i need this project for my university (but my field is cyber security so... i know little about android developing) please if you can help me!!!??? this is a matter of life and death

The error most likely comes from here:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false //
}

When you add the Google Servies plunging, there is no need to apply any version. So please change the marked line of code to:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.google.services) //
}


thank you for your answer! unfortunately, if i change it to alias(libs.plugins.google.services) Android studio marks "google" red and says its "unresolved version catalog" maybe there is something i don't have or maybe didn't install??? do you have any guesses??? sorry for this and thank you for your answer!

update: i created a new project and changed build configuration language from kotlin to groovy, then did everything again, went to firebase site and followed their instruction, then added apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' in app level and on a project level buildscript {     dependencies {         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'     }
AND IT WORKED
i honestly dont know how and now i have a new fear that tomorrow nothing will work again BUT FOR NOW ITS WORKING THANK YOU
